# What was considered the Judge's secondary weapon?

Tags: movie, comics, dredd

So near the beginning of the 2012 movie...

> **Judge Dredd:** A rookie Judge on assessment is likely to be involved in armed combat. One in five don't survive the first day. You may be required to carry out on-the-spot executions of convicted felons.
>
> **Anderson:** Yes, sir.
>
> **Judge Dredd:** Incorrect sentencing is an automatic fail. Disobeying a direct order from your assessment officer is an automatic fail. **Losing your *primary* weapon or having it taken from you is an automatic fail**.
>
> **Anderson:** Yes, sir.

Dredd later into the film is down on ammunition. I didn't seem him reach for a *secondary* weapon hopefully not just out of ignorance. Not to suggest that having a primary weapon means you have another. I feel like it is strongly implied. Anderson also has her, from what I saw, only weapon relinquished.

Do Judges have secondary weapons that are more than just resorting to pugilistic tendencies?  I am looking primarily for a movie based answer but I am more than willing to accept comic references for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Judge Dredd's "*primary weapon*" is undoubtedly his [Lawgiver](http://judgedredd.wikia.com/wiki/Lawgiver) gun but he does also carries some ***secondary* weapons** as part of his standard arsenal:

- A [Daystick](http://judgedredd.wikia.com/wiki/Daystick) cudgel; titanium-reinforced, capable of blocking blows and dispensing skull-cracking justice

[image]

- A [Bootknife](http://judgedredd.wikia.com/wiki/Boot_Knife); A sharpened blade typically carried in the boot. Used as a backup/melee weapon. We see Judge Anderson's in the 2012 film.

[image]

Comment: I am not crazy though in that I didn't see Dredd use a secondary weapon in the movie at least. I also wonder if Karl Urban got cramps from frowning so much.

Comment: @Matt - No. We see him punching people a lot, but I can't recall any time he uses a weapon other than his lawgiver.

Comment: @Valorum He uses two grenades - one gas grenade, and one stun grenade. Further, although the Lawgiver is a judge's "primary" weapon, that doesn't stop a judge from using anything else as a secondary or improvised weapon, as Anderson does when she loses her sidearm.